# Simple way of blocking a program on CentOS 6?

Tags: centos

One of our user has been compiling their own program within their home directory. Normally we don't mind, but this particular program has a memory leak and eats into the SWAP. We have told this user many times not to run the program and yet she wouldn't listen.

Is there a simple way of blocking a certain program from running?

Comment: change user's shell to `/sbin/nologin`

Comment: Get rid of the user.

Comment: If the user changes her mind and wants to cooperate, tell her how (and make it easy for her) she can start the program with a self-imposed memory limit set up using `ulimit` (`setrlimit`) or `cgroups`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Two ways:

- Use `limits.conf` to assign the maximum allotted memory per process for that user
- Create a `cgroup` for that user in order to limit their total memory usage

More details here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34334/how-to-create-a-user-with-limited-ram-usage

Comment: I'm not a fan of technological solutions here. The user has demonstrated a willingness to harm the server and its other user, despite repeated warnings. IT shouldn't be doing extra work to keep them in jail, the user should lose access and probably be fired if they're an employee.

Comment: One should also have a system that enforces policy, rather than just banning users after the fact.

Comment: @ceejayoz Or, if one must implement a technological solution, at least have some fun with it.  "You say that when you ran your program again, it deleted all your files?  Weird.  Well, we told you not to run it again, didn't we?"

Comment: I think annoying would be eough to solve the matter. Something in the line of resetting password so she has to make a walk/call everytime.

Comment: I would take this as a solution. I know most people agree that we should just ban the user for stop them from logging onto the servers. Unfortunately it doesn't work like that in a scientific research environment.

Comment: @lbanz My sympathies. While that's a tough spot, a professor who ruined a lecture hall regularly so subsequent classes couldn't use it would probably see themselves sanctioned. If it's possible to go to their supervisor/dean to get them reprimanded, it'd probably be worthwhile.

Answer (score 11):

You are trying to solve a human problem via technical means. This person is knowingly violating policy. The appropriate response is to (as @ceejayoz wisely mentioned above) get rid of that user, or at the very least, remove access to the system in question and any others like it.

Answer (score 4):

If you have home directories on a separate partition you can mount the partition with `noexec`. Although I'd also agree to just ban the user.

Comment: This may be bypassed by calling `ld` directly and passing the path of the file you want to execute as an argument.